# Connecting to a VPN box on my LAN, while connected via VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I've recently configured an old laptop to sit on my home network, and I have it sending all of its traffic through an OpenVPN connection.  It's running Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm still able to connect to this laptop from other computers on the LAN via SSH and web browsers.

Now, I've also set up my wireless router to run a PPTP VPN server, so that I can connect to my home network from work (with a MacBook).  When I do that, however, I'm able to see the other computers on the LAN, but *not* the VPN'd laptop.

I'm assuming that when I'm connected through the VPN server, my traffic to the laptop is being routed through the wrong interface, but my networking-fu isn't strong enough to know where or how to fix this.  Any thoughts?

Some information about my setup:

- Router: ASUS RT-N66U with merlin firmware (192.168.1.1)
- LAN DHCP pool: 192.168.1.2-254
- Router VPN server client pool: 192.168.10.2-11
- VPN laptop (192.168.1.20)

Comment: What do you mean by "see" the VPN'd laptop ? Does the laptop run some sort of autodiscover service such as Bonjour or Samba ? Can you still manually ping it on its IP ?

Comment: Assuming the router can see the laptop, you can forward some unused port on the router to point to the port in the VPN'd laptop on which the VPN server is listening. You would need to know the Internet IP address of your router; the easiest way is if your router can support a Dynamic DNS service such as [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/), so you could from work point your VPN client to your laptop simply as `myself.noip.com:port`. Let me know if you are interested in this method.

Comment: Nope, I can't ping the box, nor can I access any of the http services running on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I found my solution:

The problem was that my router placed VPN clients on a different subnet (192.168.10.0) than the other DHCP clients (192.168.1.0).  I changed the router's DHCP pool to 192.168.1.1-200, and the VPN client pool to 192.168.1.201-210, and now everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

way to complicated 
a simpler and way easier solution is to try Tinc VPN
http://www.tinc-vpn.org/

then you dont need OpenVPN, PPTP etc..

with tinc you can set it up on the machines you want in your little private vpn, it does not matter where.

tinc will find the *nodes* it self using a master node that needs to be a server that all *nodes* can connect to to find each other

how it works presentation 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7P_vvz1AP8